# how to upload files to onedrive for business through drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, onedrive

I have a drupal site and an oneDrive for business account. My site has a software section through which we provide software to download for public. What we use to do is that we upload the software in our ODFB account, create a download link, then put the link after the description of the software.

What I wanted to do is that while posting the software, there should be an option to upload the software. And the file should go straight to our ODFB account instead of the server where the website is hosted.
Is it possible? Any module available?

Comment: There are likely many more people that may know the answer to this over at the Drupal stack exchange.  I would recommend migrating or duplicating your question there.  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible using the OneDrive upload APIs. If the file size is less than 100MB, you should be able to use the simple item upload API:

https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_put.htm

However, if the file is larger, you can use resumable item upload API:

https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_large_files.htm

With the right permissions, you can access your OneDrive for Business using /drives endpoint and save the file there.